# Not able to read a sysfs file

Tags: file, sysfs, msr

I am trying to read the Machine Specific Registers (MSRs) by reading the sysfs files `/dev/cpu/0/msr`. It usually has read-write permissions for only the root. I update those permissions to 666 (of course using the sudo rights) and then try to read the file as a normal user. It doesn't allow me to do that. However, if I try to open the file with `sudo` it allows me to open the file and read.

I also tried to change the ownership of the file using `chown` command. Currently the status of the file is the following:

```
[my-user@machine-name]$ ls -l /dev/cpu/0/msr
crw-rw-rw-. 1 my-user root 202, 0 Oct 25 16:23 /dev/cpu/0/msr
```

Ehat do I need to do to access the file as a normal user?

Answer (score 0):

As you can find in [MSR man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/msr.4.html):

> This file is protected so that it can be read and written only by the user root, or members of the group root.

[Here is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18661976/reading-dev-cpu-msr-from-userspace-operation-not-permitted) similar question and you can find instructions how to grant permission to access these files there.

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't allow me to change the file capabilities. I do the following (I have also copied the response):

[my-user@machine-name 0]$ sudo setcap cap_sys_rawio+ep readmsr
Failed to set capabilities on file `readmsr' (Operation not supported)
usage: setcap [-q] [-v] (-r|-|<caps>) <filename> [ ... (-r|-|<capsN>) <filenameN> ]

 Note <filename> must be a regular (non-symlink) file.

Comment: Your kernel may not support capabilities. Try this instead: `chmod u+s readmsr` - set suid bit on your executable. Or simply run it as root.