# Executing rdmsr / wrmsr with secure boot on?

Tags: linux, code-signing, kernel-module, msr

I'm trying to undervolt my CPU on a Intel Skylake machine running Ubuntu 18.04 / kernel 4.18.0-16 in Secure Boot mode and need to read/write MSR 0x150. I have [signed and loaded the msr.ko kernel module](https://askubuntu.com/questions/789888/wrmsr-not-working-since-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04/790277), but can't run the executables rdmsr and wrmsr from msr-tools, even as root / super user (I get permission errors). What I grasp is that with newer kernels (> 3.7?) you can't access the MSRs from user space. There are workarounds described: I tried [setting "setcap cap_sys_rawio+ep" for both rdmsr and wrmsr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18661976/reading-dev-cpu-msr-from-userspace-operation-not-permitted), but that didn't help. I'm using the tools [iuvolt](https://github.com/tiziw/iuvolt) and [undervolt](https://github.com/georgewhewell/undervolt), but also tried wrmsr directly.
How can I execute rdmsr / wrmsr in secure boot mode?

[Here](https://github.com/intel/intel-cmt-cat/wiki/UEFI-Secure-Boot-Compatibility) and [here](https://astojanov.github.io/blog/2013/05/30/intel-pcm.html) is some info and an old patch to make it work with Secure boot. But the code is totally different now.

Comment: Why do you think this is related to Secure Boot?  Does it suddenly work if Secure Boot is turned off?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what happens. But I don't want to disable Secure Boot if possible.

Comment: Did you make any progress on this? I'm having the exact same issue.

Comment: I ended up turning off Secure Boot. I keep running into all kinds of issues with it anyway.